# C# EF Core query vs list filtering performance

Tags: c#, list, sorting, filter, entity-framework-core

### Current situation

I have a database with a lot of entries. By a search field, only the results should be displayed, which correspond to the search criteria. The whole program should run as performant as possible.

### Problem

The data has to be filtered several times and the filter can be reset.
Since I want to be as efficient as possible, I now asked myself, is it better to do this via EF-Core, i.e. SQL or filtering lists?

### Thinking

I thought about sending a new query to the database for each filter specification using EF-Core. However, the queries can take a long time to complete and the input text often changes rapidly. My other approach would be to first read all the data from the database and store it in a list. This list I then have to store and display a new filtered list. With this approach, I would have the list twice in my memory.

Would there be another possibility, which I did not consider here?

> Note: I can't filter the current list because I continue to use it and
> I am working with MVVM.

**Edit:**
I am working with a data set, that has over 10'000 records. The majority of the columns are strings, with a length between 10 and 100 characters. I need to search trough all these characters, to find the containing search therm. I have to filter the datasource on every keypress, so i cant trothle the input. The database is on a local mobile device. My question is, what is the fastest way?

The queries are currently generatet by EF-Core with the code:

```
where : b => b.Username.Contains(search) || b.Name.Contains(search) || b.Country.State.Contains(search);
```

`

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> ReadTablesAsync(Expression<Func<Person, bool>> where = null)
{
    using (MobileDbContext ctx = GetMobileDbContext())
    {
        var queryInclude = ctx.Person.Include(b => b.Country).OrderBy(b => b.Username);
        return where != null ? queryInclude.Where(where).ToList() : queryInclude.ToList();
    }
}
```

`

```
//From the database. This list will not be changed.
IEnumerable<Person> listFromDB = await MobileDataStore.PersonenLesenAsync();
            
//Create on every search therm a new filtered list
ObservableCollection<Person> filteringList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
filteringList.Clear();
filteringList.AddRange(listFromDB.Where(where);
```

**Example:**

I need to find a person with the name "Karl" , but  in the code I dont  know if it is the name, username, country or  something else. So I have  to search trough all the records to show possible results.

Comment: You haven't given anyone enough context to help you.  How large is the data set? What is its footprint in memory vs the target machines you are running on? What do the queries look like? Are you throttling the input text to ensure that you are not flooding the application until the user stops typing?  There are probably a dozen more questions that also need to be asked and answered before anyone can give you a reasonable recommendation.

Comment: An example instead of a description could also help a lot

Comment: `the input text often changes rapidly.` Use debounce to kick off the query periodically not on every keypress.

Comment: The fastest way is going to be to have everything in memory. Since you haven't specified the total size of your database, we can't really advise further.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using this query just to send the data to the UI, you can add .AsNoTracking to increase performance.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

You can also check:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/performance-diagnosis